# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down

Tags: linux, jsch

I use follawing code to execute commands on Linux via Windows:

```
  JSch jsch=new JSch();  
    Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session.setConfig(props);
    session.setPassword(pwd);
    session.connect();
    ChannelShell channel = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel("shell");
    boolean ch = channel.isConnected();
    channel.sendSignal("ls");
    channel.connect();
    boolean ch1 = channel.isConnected();
```

But it fails on line `channel.connect();`:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:172)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:132)
```

How fix such error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsch : how to keep the session alive and up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127200/jsch-how-to-keep-the-session-alive-and-up)

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate because it's a new session.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some polling where you can check active status of session. for reference you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175162/1850650)  `link`