# Getting exception "session is down" when calling the ftp server through jsch

Tags: java, groovy, jsch

When I am trying to get connected with the ftp server for file uploading, I am getting exception `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down`

Code is in groovy:

```
String SFTPHOST = "########"
int SFTPPORT = 22
String SFTPUSER = "########"
String SFTPPASS = "########"
String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/QA/"
ChannelSftp sftp = null
Session session = null

try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch()
    session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT)
    session.setPassword(SFTPPASS)
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
            "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password")

    session.connect()
    Channel channel = session.openChannel "sftp"
    channel.connect()
    sftp = channel as ChannelSftp
    sftp.cd SFTPWORKINGDIR
    File f = new File("Demo.csv")
    sftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName())
    //def fileList = sftp.ls("*")
    println fileList.size()
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error message that you're getting, including the stack trace.

Comment: that was some other issue it got solved...this the current scenario

Comment: i debugged a little and found out that in the session.openChannel() method it is failing at the following line : if(!isConnected){
      throw new JSchException("session is down");
    }

Comment: So did you debug `session.connect()` to see how it comes it neither connects nor throws an exception? + How do you even pass the `StrictHostKeyChecking=yes`, if you do not specify a host key anywhere?

Comment: i have tried by setting StrictHostKeyChecking=no, i am getting the same exception.

Comment: I never recommended you to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`! I just wrote that with `=yes` (what is the right way), you need more code. Anyway, you didn't answer my primary question: *Did you debug `session.connect()` to see how it comes it neither connects nor throws an exception?*

Comment: I got the issue...Actually JSch is not an FTP client it's an SSH client (with an included SFTP implementation). And the ftp server which i am connecting with is not a ssh server. That's why jsch is unable to connect with that ftp server. I have used apache commons ftp client and its working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsch : how to keep the session alive and up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127200/jsch-how-to-keep-the-session-alive-and-up)

Answer (score -1):

I got the issue...Actually JSch is not an FTP client it's an SSH client (with an included SFTP implementation). And the ftp server which i am connecting with is not a ssh server. That's why jsch is unable to connect with that ftp server. I have used apache commons ftp client and its working fine