# JSch create a embed ssh connection but ServerAliveInterval not works

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

I want use JSch as a common shell interactive tool, it's really useful.

I want create a ssh which is inner JSch channel shell and the shell's InputStream and OutStream is maintained by myself.

The problem is when I send a command string, `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -T root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 22`, to `OutputStream` to setting a keep-live by `ServerAliveInterval` but it not works at all.the new channel will hold 1 min when I close network.This time is more over my config `ServerAliveInterval=5 ServerAliveCountMax=2`.

Is JSch support inner ssh connection setting to handle keep-alive check, such as `ServerAliveInterval`?

#### UPDATE

some step to describe the question:
1. create a shell channel use JSch to login `host1`
2. use the channel jump to `host2` by send a command `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 22` which is a byte stream. The new ssh is config with `ServerAliveInterval` to check ssh network status of `host2`.

JSch can recognize `host1` is disconnect if I'm use `Session.setServerAliveInterval` method and test it with `Session.isConnected`.
The problem is `host2` can't be checked if only `host2` network is break even through I'm use `ServerAliveInterval` config when jump to `host2`.It will hold a long time (more then 1min on my test) until get a `packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe`. But I'm expect some error message arrived less then 10 seconds as the  `ServerAliveInterval=5 ServerAliveCountMax=2` was set.

Comment: Do I understand right, that you expect that sending `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=5` to a shell session (created by JSch) affects the session itself?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, the problem is that the setting not has a affect inner jsch shell channel.

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems my bug, I'm fixing.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is so confusing. You do not have anything like *"inner jsch shell channel"*. + Anyway, if you manually login with a regular SSH terminal client and type your command on command-line, does it stay alive or not?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, It can stay alive.With some research, I find it's a difficult to transfer shell stream data to a normal function call in program(consider network fail etc).Using a shell channel jump to another host is also dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is a black box for JSCh.

JSch is not aware of anything that you do there.

If you want to emulate, what OpenSSH `ServerAliveInterval` directive does, use [`Session.setServerAliveInterval`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setServerAliveInterval-int-).

See also [JSch: How to keep the session alive and up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16127200/850848).

Comment: hi, I have attempt the config, but sorry, it not work. This set method only effect JSch's straight shell channel which it connect host but the sub ssh created inner the shell channel will not be check connection state.For detail, see my update above.Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry, the problem seems my bug, I'm fixing.